# How To Make a DIV stop wrapping

Tags: css, word-wrap

How to make a div stop wrapping?

Comment: Hi Jay, I know your problem is fixed. You may find in future you can experiment with styling using the developer tools in ie and chrome. You can make live changes in the browser to see how the style will look. When you have the style you want you can copy and paste it to your actual css sheets

Comment: thanks and yes I know, but I am limited to firefox here where I am at :-\

Comment: install firebug for mozilla and I think it does the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Set this style on your div. It works in Chrome and IE. I haven't tested other browsers.

```
overflow: auto;
```

Comment: are you setting it like user2380032 has answered? That does work as I'm guessing you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want `<div class="objectives">` to appear below `<div class="icon">`? If so, `div.objectives { clear: left; }` should do the trick.

Or do you want the entirety of `<div class="objectives">` to appear alongside `<div class="icon">`? If so, `div.objectives { float:left; }` should make it happen. You may also need to specify a width on `div.objectives`. Alternatively, remove the float code and set both `div.objectives` and `div.icon` to `{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }`.

Comment: yes I want the entirety of <div class="objectives"> to appear alongside <div class="icon">? If so, div.objectives { float:left; } should make it happen. 
So that would work even if the DIV class="icon" is floated left? I'll try it

Comment: just to be clear, I want it to be on the RIGHT side of the icon.

Comment: I set a width of 299px for "objectives". When I select "inspect element" in firefox I see that the div objectives starts way to the same space that "icon" starts at, even though .icon is floated left and has a margin-right of 10px

Comment: They'd both the floated left and would appear in source order, so yes, it would work. That said, I'll defer to @user2380032 and @RobWhite. Setting `div.objectives { overflow:auto; }` is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

This works just edit the code and replace it with the code below

```
<div class="icon"><img align="left" alt="" src="/resource/uploads_scope/issues/090113/090113_pairedText_featuredSkills.png"></div>
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <h5>Featured Skills:</h5>
        <p>Compare and contrast; vocabulary; shades of meaning.<br>
        <strong>Other Key Skills: forming and supporting a claim, inference, author’s craft, key ideas.</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ahh thanks! Tha did the trick. I'll study that and try to understand the code and concept behind it. My positioning is CSS is my weakest point. Thanks again, I'll vote it up.

Comment: well, it's just the positioning issues where I run into trouble, and of course with responsiveness now. How would that even transpire though, via video chats?

Comment: somewhat with php, no java at all

Comment: what I REALLY need to learn, besides CSS positioning, and responsive design is JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: I can't find any way to contact you on your profile, onlyCoding